# Make phonegap app load index.html on load

Tags: cordova

Say I have just created a new project via the command line.

How I can go from this new project that displays Hello World, ProjectName to one that displays assets/www/index.html upon application open?

(Sorry for the rookie question, but I couldn't find documentation on it for some reason even though it should be all over the place..)

Comment: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://cleancodedevelopment-qualityseal.blogspot.com/2012/12/first-phonegap-app-with-android-using.html

Copy the files stated to the project.